# Spring MVC - fill model on the form

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I want to fill the form according to the related book when I click the view or update the link on the page. I know, there is a solution with opening another page but I want to do it on the same page. As you can see on the picture below I can properly get the list on the left table.  I have tried a post method below but did not work. So what would you recommend to do it?

[image]

Controller class:

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/listbooks")
  public String getBook(@ModelAttribute BookConfig bookConfig, Model model)
      throws IOException {

    model.addAttribute("book", bookConfig);

    return "list";
  }

  @GetMapping(path = "/listbooks")
  public String showAllBooks(Model model) throws IOException {

    model.addAttribute("books", bookService.getBookConfigList());

    return "list";
  }
```

HTML file:

```
   <div class="table-responsive" th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(books)}">
                    <table class="table table-hover" style="height:50px;">
                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>View</th>
                            <th>Update</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
                            <td th:text="${book.name}">Book Name</td>
                            <td><a href="#" th:href="@{'/books/listbooks/'}">View</a></td>
                            <td><a href="#" th:href="@{'/books/listbooks/'}">Update</a></td>
                            <td><a href="#" th:href="@{''}">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
```

This is what I am trying to do on the HTML file:

```
 <form th:if="${book != null}" th:object="${book}" th:action="@{/book/}"
                          method="post">

    <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"
                               ">Edit
                                Book Configuration</h4>
                        </div>


                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group"
                                >
                                    <label>Book name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>

                                </div>

...
```

I have solved using JavaScript, Firstly, I have adjusted the getBook method below

```
 @PostMapping("/books")
  public String getBook(@RequestBody String bookName) throws IOException {

    return "list";
  }
```

and then I have add these two JS functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".view").click(function () {

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");  // Find the row
            var $text = $row.find(".bookname").text(); // get the text on the view link using its the class name  


            $.post("http://localhost:8081/books",
                {
                    bookName: $text
                },
                function (data, status) {
                    assignDataToTable(data);
                });
        });
    });

 function assignDataToTable(data) {
        alert("hey" + data);
        document.getElementById("booknameinput").value = data;

    }
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to show the data for the book on the right hand side of the page when you click a link on the left hand side of the page?

Comment: Yep, exactly @StaticBeagle

Comment: I'm guessing what you need is JavaScript (or jQuery), so when you click on a table row, it will update the form's field with the information in the clicked row. (I mean browser-side JavaScript)

Comment: As @m-alorda mentioned, you will need to roll out your own `JavaScript` to implement what you are trying to do. Since you are using `bootstrap` you already have `jQuery` as one of your includes so you could use it as well. It's a little involved but not impossible.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try to do by using JavaScript and write down here if I success :)